# Values for coefficients of even power $P(x)$ s.t. $P(x)$ has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Suppose I have an even power polynomial $P(x)=x^4+a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+1$. How do find the interval for the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $P(x)$ has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$?

> *Additionally*, how would I extend the method for finding the interval for any even power $P(x)$ with arbitrary coefficients?

I've only tried answering graphically, I have no idea to solve this analytically.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_4) can give some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $x=0$ is not a solution, dividing by $x^2$ we get
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+a_1\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+a_2=0$$ now we substitute $$x+\frac{1}{x}=t$$ then we get $$x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=t^2-2$$ and you will get a quadratic equation in $t$ to solve.
$$t^2+a_1t+a_2-2=0$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: How do I find the interval? Should I consider only the determinant?

Comment: I would consider the discriminant.

Comment: It is $$\frac{a_1^2}{4}-a_2+2$$ and it must be $$a_1^2-4a_2+8<0$$

Comment: What about higher order even polynomials?

Comment: Sorry, These Problems are all solved

Comment: I don't understand?